# C++ memory leak when method returns a copy of itself

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a c++ code similar to below. This will give a memory leak in the `Base::add` method and in `total = &(*total + *to_add);`. How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Base
{
    public:
        int n;
        Base(int input) : n(input) {}
        Base(const Base& input)
        {
            n = input.n;
        }
        Base& add(Base &other, bool new_obj=true)
        {
            Base *self;
            if (new_obj) {
                self = new Base(other);
            } else {
                self = this;
            }
            self->n += other.n;
            return *self;
        }
        Base& operator+=(Base &other)
        {
            return this->add(other, false);
        }
};
Base& operator+(Base &self, Base &other)
{
    return self.add(other);
}
class A : public Base
{
    using Base::Base;
    std::string print() {
        return "Class A method_a";
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    using Base::Base;
    std::string print() {
        return "Class B method_b";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *total = new Base(0);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        Base *to_add = new A(i);
        total = &(*total + *to_add);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        Base *to_add = new B(i);
        total = &(*total + *to_add);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be able to answer you need to explain what you want to accomplish. That will give an idea about the ownership of the newly created objects. Should they become children?

Comment: Return by value instead of pointer.

Comment: `self = new Base(other);` You never call a corrsponding `delete`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He does not do -> memory leak. But he can't either, as this would invalidate the returned reference. Some kind egg/hen problem, or round in the circle...

Comment: I want the `Base::add` method to give an option to either create a new object or apply it to the existing object

Answer (score 1):

C++ isn't Java, you should return by value. It is unclear from your example what purpose the derived classes serve, so I assume that you don't really need them:

```
#include <iostream>
class Base
{
    public:
        int n;
        Base(int input) : n(input) {}
        Base(const Base& input) = default;
};

Base& operator+=(Base &x, const Base &y)
{
    x.n += y.n;
    return x;
}

Base operator+(const Base &x, const Base &y)
{
    return Base(x.n + y.n);
}

int main()
{
    Base total(0);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        total += Base(i); // way 1
    }
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        total = total + Base(i); // way 2
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about returning new C++11 rvalue reference with `operator+`?

Comment: @Aconcagua: How does it change anything? Who would be responsible to delete it if it is dynamically allocated?

Comment: I don't want to get back at dynamic allocation at all: `Base&& operator+(/*...*/) { return Base(x.n + y.n); }`. It seems a good idea to me to allow move semantics and I wanted to ask you for your opinion, so the question mark actually is a true question mark...

Comment: @Aconcagua: adding `&&` does not magically use "move semantics". On the contrary, the code I posted that returns by value will use the move constructor if available (but usually will just elide the move or the copy). Returning an r-value reference to a temporary is still just that, returning a reference to a temporary that is destroyed when you exit the function, and thus triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: Classic reference (pre c++11) or pointer to local variable is absolutely clear. Not yet firm with "new" references, though, had to code too long with C++ 98/03 yet...

Answer (score 0):

```
total = &(*total + *to_add);
```

Why are you doing this to yourself?
doesn't `total = (total + to_add)` work for you?

It seems to me as if you're trying to do contradictory stuff here...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your Base::add function is trivial and you can modify it as follows:

```
        Base& add(Base &other)
    {
        n += other.n;
        return *this;
    }
```